How to use Intent.ACTION_SEND share text with image to Line app?
I'm trying to sharing text with image to Line, but when I put it together, it only show image but not text, is there other way to do this or Line just not support this? (it's work when share by gmail and discord)
below is my code:
public void share(){
    Drawable drawable = ContextCompat.getDrawable(this, R.drawable.image);
    Bitmap bitmap = ((BitmapDrawable) drawable).getBitmap();
    // Save the bitmap to a file
    try {
        File file = new File(getExternalCacheDir(), "shared_image.png");
        FileOutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream(file);
        bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, outputStream);
        outputStream.flush();
        outputStream.close();
        Uri imageUri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(this,  "com.example.myapplication.provider", file);
        // Create the share intent
        Intent shareIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
        shareIntent.setType("image/*");
        shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "HI");
        shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, imageUri);
        shareIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);

        startActivity(Intent.createChooser(shareIntent, "Share Image"));
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}


Looks like the issue is that some apps, like Line, don’t support sharing both an image and text together in the same share intent, especially if you’re setting the type as image/*. Some apps just won’t handle both at once.
1 -> You can try using Intent.ACTION_SEND_MULTIPLE instead, which lets you share both text and images. Here’s the updated code:
Intent shareIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND_MULTIPLE);
shareIntent.setType("*/*")
           .putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "HI")
           .putParcelableArrayListExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, new ArrayList<>(Collections.singletonList(imageUri)))
           .addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);

This way, you can include both text and the image more easily.
2 -> If Line just won’t allow text and images together, you could share a link to the text (like a webpage) along with the image, or you could add the text to the image itself. It’s just a platform limitation, so you’ll need to work around it a bit.

I try first method but is the same, my current project requirements need to generate image dynamically, so I can't use second way too, but still thanks to reply, it should be the Line restrict :( .
